# Rails : Backbone + Turbolinks Hybrid Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, turbolinks

I'm building a Rails 4 application and I'm trying to combine location.hash
Backbone History with turbolinks push state. The application is broken up into
multiple smaller, SPA like pages.

### Example of Problem

The problem I'm having is that when I do `Backbone.Router.navigate()`, within
a page, it doesn't register anything with turbolinks. Here's a hypothetical
example to demonstrate the problem:

1. Visit `/one`
2. `@router.navigate 'page-one'`
3. Location becomes `/one#page-one`
4. `@router.navigate 'page-two'`
5. Location becomes `/one#page-two`
6. Click on link to `/two`
7. Turbolinks intercepts and navigates to `/two`
8. Click on the Back Button, you are still stuck on `/two`
9. Click on the Back Button again, you are still stuck on `/two`
10. Click on the Back Button a third time, you are brought back to `/one`

### What I Tried

I guessed that what's probably happening is that when navigating via backbone,
the browser is logging the change but turbolinks isn't. I tried to expose
`Turbolinks.reflectNewUrl`:

*[turbolinks.js.coffee](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/blob/master/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee)*

```
@Turbolinks = { visit, pagesCached, reflectNewUrl }
```

And then modifying `Backbone.Router.navigate` so that it registers with
turbolinks every time we navigate:

```
navigate = Backbone.Router.prototype.navigate
Backbone.Router.prototype.navigate = (page, args...) ->
  navigate page, args...
  window?.Turbolinks?.reflectNewUrl "##{page}"
```

That *sort of* worked, **Step 8** above is no longer stuck on `/two`, but
click on the back button again and we get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null turbolinks.js:142
removeNoscriptTags turbolinks.js:142
changePage turbolinks.js:111
fetchHistory turbolinks.js:69
(anonymous function) turbolinks.js:390
```

So something is still wrong.

Now I'm hoping there's a kind soul out there to help me out and point out my
perhaps obvious blunder :)

Comment: Why are you trying to mix two different (and probably incompatible) single page application systems?

Comment: well it started off being a normal rails app, but now we're looking at building a mindmapping system on one of the views - want to be able to  navigate via history to different points in the map. happy to drop turbolinks if there's no alternative but it'd be nice to keep both

Comment: Backbone and Turbolinks are fundamentally incompatible because of how they interact with the browser's push state. Also, Turbolinks is essentially a shim to speed up loading full HTML pages and Backbone is a data modeling layer that can interact more directly with your app. They are completely different, so I wouldn't try to conflate them together.

Comment: Why can't you use Backbone routers and pushState to "be able to navigate via history to different points in the map"?

Comment: muistooshort, I am using backbone routers although with pushstate off, turning it on brings more complexities to the table since backbone will need to know about rails routes - and still experiencing the same problem after trying with pushstate on.

TimDorr, you're probably right. I'm hoping that since Backbone routing can use location.hash rather than pushState there's a way around it. 

Not sure if this GH issue is relevant: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues/256

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I disagree about not mixing Turbolinks and Backbone. They fulfil different roles and there are occasions where you might like to use both.

In fact, I understand Basecamp uses both.

You can use this (now infamous) post as a starting point: http://www.goddamnyouryan.com/blog/rails-4-turbolinks-and-backbone

However I still had the problem you're having. Here's how I solved it (provisionally, I haven't tested this in the wild):

```
window.MyApp =
  Models: {}
  Collections: {}
  Views: {}
  Routers: {}

  initialize: ->
    # Build it up
    @router = new MyApp.Routers.Pages(data)
    Backbone.history.start()

  close: ->
    # Tear it down
    @router.close(false)
    @router = undefined

# Turbolinks exposes the before-change event when a page change is initiated
$(document).on 'page:before-change', ->
  # If the app has been initialized
  if MyApp.router?

    # Stop the history and clean up the app
    Backbone.history.stop()
    MyApp.close()

    # We're leaving the domain of the backbone app, check for Turbolinks
    if Turbolinks?.supported
      # Push the last known state of the app to the Turbolinks history
      window.history.replaceState {turbolinks: true, url: window.location.href}, window.title, window.location.href

$(document).on 'page:change', ->
  # If it's the page with our backbone app
  if $('#pages').size() > 0
    MyApp.initialize()
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I tried this but couldn't get it to work. There are two things that I'm encountering:
1. Backbone.Router does not seem to have a close() method. Should I use Marionette.AppRouter?

2. The when going back and forth between backbone and non-backbone pages, I get an error saying: `Uncaught Error: Backbone.history has already been started`

Did anyone else encounter this?

Comment: `@router.close()` in this context is just any close method you use to clear up your router. You can define it yourself or leave it out if you want.

Comment: I elaborated a bit on this and tried to explain why it works in a blog post here: https://medium.com/@midhir/rails-building-a-single-page-backbone-app-without-sacrificing-turbolinks-3e22841cf834

Answer (score -1):

```
window.Summerland =
  Models: {}
  Collections: {}
  Views: {}
  Routers: {}
  initialize: ->
    new Summerland.Routers.Application
    Backbone.history.start pushState: true

$(document).ready ->
  Summerland.initialize()

$(document).on 'page:load', ->
  Backbone.history.stop()
  Summerland.initialize()
```